# ASP.NET MVC API with WebForms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create an ASP.NET MVC API Authorization filter, the reason for this is that I would like for my API to work with both the session login and an API key.

So if the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` it true, do nothing. If no find the parameter API key and validate it and the user for this request only.
I have tried the following below, but when I get into the action it is called is the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` just empty and `IsAuthenticated` is false.

public class MyAccessFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private DatabaseEntities database;

```
public MyAccessFilter()
{
    database = new DatabaseEntities();   
}

public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    // If the users is already authed is this a local call, user id should be set
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return continuation();

    // Find the api key and log in with it

    IEnumerable<string> apiKeyHeader;
    if (!actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("apikey", out apiKeyHeader))
        return failed();
    if(apiKeyHeader.Count() != 1)
        return failed();
    string key = apiKeyHeader.First();


    //var key = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["apikey"] as string;
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        return failed();

    var userid = (from f in database.Users where f.ApiKey == key select f.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (userid == 0)
    {
        return failed();
    }

    var usernameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userid.ToString());
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { usernameClaim }, "ApiKey");
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

    return continuation();
}

private Task<HttpResponseMessage> failed()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
    tcs.SetResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive it from `AuthorizeAttribute` and implement OnAuthorization method. See for  [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148050/custom-authorizations-in-web-api)